# SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame See the caveats in the documentation:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, view, copy

i'm trying to send a request to a website then get the scrape the Text out of the website. however  i get warning.

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy _df['text']=remove_one_words_from_list(website_text,_df['language']).copy()

i already tried `.copy()` and  the issue still remains and also with `_df.loc` i get `too many indexers` error. **It's important to note that** the dataframe that i pass is in for loop soi call `get_the_text2` method in a for loop then pass a row each time

```
    def get_the_text2(_df):
  '''
  sending a request for second time with a different method to recieve the Text of the Articles

  Parameters
  ----------
  _df : DataFrame
  
  Returns
  -------
  only the text contained in the url
  '''  
  df['text']=''
#   for k,i in enumerate(_df['url']):
  if str(_df):
        website_text=list()
        print(_df)   
        #time.sleep(2)
        try:
          response=requests.get(_df['url'],headers={"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"})              
          status_code=response.status_code
          soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
          
          if len(website_text)<=10:
                      website_text=list()
                      if soup.article:
                          if soup.article.find_all(['p',re.compile("^h\d{1}")]):   
                              for data in soup.article.find_all(['p',re.compile("^h\d{1}")]):                          
                                  website_text.append(data.get_text(strip=True))            
                              #df.at[k,'text']=remove_one_words_from_list(website_text,df.at[k,'language'])
                              _df['text']=remove_one_words_from_list(website_text,_df['language']).copy()
                              print('****ARTICLE P & H{1}****',remove_one_words_from_list(website_text,_df['language']))

for _index,item in enumerate(df['status_code']):
  if item !=200:
    get_the_text2(df.loc[_index])
```

### **EDIT**:

just to show the error message with `.loc`

my Code:

`_df['text']=remove_one_words_from_list(website_text,_df.loc[:,'language']).copy()`

error message:

```
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 102
    100 for _index,item in enumerate(df['status_code']):
    101   if item !=200:
--> 102     get_the_text2(df.loc[_index])

File c:\Users\\anaconda3\envs\GDELT\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:939, in _LocationIndexer._validate_key_length(self, key)
    937             raise IndexingError(_one_ellipsis_message)
    938         return self._validate_key_length(key)
--> 939     raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
    940 return key

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

### EDIT 2

found out if i use this `.loc['language']` it won't throw error although the `SettingWithCopyWarning` is still there.

```
_df['text']=remove_one_words_from_list(website_text,_df.loc['language']).copy()
```

according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/4575197) i know why it's happened but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Show your try with `loc` and the full error message caused by it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher i added `.loc` version of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to assign the new value to a ***new Dataframe*** and this did the job.

```
_df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=list(df.columns)) # to get the columns from the original Dataframe
_df2['text']=remove_one_words_from_list(website_text,_df.loc['language']).copy()
```